# Use @Mapping with expression to parse OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am trying to write a Mapper between my internal Entity class and my DTO class using `org.mapstruct.Mapper`. The Entity class contains a field `startDate` of type `String` that is mapped to a field `startDate` of type `OffsetDateTime`.

To map those fields I am using `@Mapping` with an expression like this:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.TARGET_IMMUTABLE)
public interface InstanceMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "startDate", expression = "java(OffsetDateTime.parse(source.getStartDate()))")
    InstanceDTO toInstanceDTO(Instance source);

    @Mapping(target = "startDate", expression = "java(source.getStartDate().toString())")
    Instance toInstance(InstanceDTO source);
}
```

The second `@Mapping` compiles correctly but at compilation I get the following error because of the `@Mapping(target = "startDate", expression = "java(OffsetDateTime.parse(source.getStartDate()))")`:

```
[ERROR] project/target/generated-sources/annotations/path/service/mappers/InstanceMapperImpl.java error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable OffsetDateTime
[ERROR]   location: class InstanceMapperImpl
```

Adding an unused import to the InstanceMapper.java file does not solve the error, as it seems to be removed at compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as the error is basically a missing import, I'm reasonably sure you can solve this by using a fully qualified name (i.e. `java.time.OffsetDateTime`) in your expression:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.TARGET_IMMUTABLE)
public interface InstanceMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "startDate", expression = "java(java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(source.getStartDate()))")
    InstanceDTO toInstanceDTO(Instance source);

    @Mapping(target = "startDate", expression = "java(source.getStartDate().toString())")
    Instance toInstance(InstanceDTO source);
}
```